# User implementation of memcpy, where to optimize further?

Tags: performance, c, reinventing-the-wheel

Edit:

By adding the restrict keyword I was able to get my memcpy up to speed with the library implementation (and in this particular test, exceeding the library implementations speed). New results:

| Test case | `mem_cpy` | `mem_cpy_naive` | `memcpy` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| big string (1000 bytes) | **2.584988s** | 3.936075s | 3.952187s |
| small string (8 bytes) | 0.025931s | 0.051899s | **0.025807s** |

Note: I tested also it as a part of a bigger implementation I had been working on. Previously I gained about 20% performance by swapping the libc memcpy in place of my own, now there was no difference.

Updated code:

```c
static void
copy_words(void *restrict dst, const void *restrict src, size_t words)
{
    const uint64_t  *restrict src64;
    uint64_t        *restrict dst64;
    uint64_t        pages;
    uint64_t        offset;

    pages = words / 8;
    offset = words - pages * 8;
    src64 = (const uint64_t *restrict)src;
    dst64 = (uint64_t *restrict)dst;
    while (pages--)
    {
        *dst64++ = *src64++;
        *dst64++ = *src64++;
        *dst64++ = *src64++;
        *dst64++ = *src64++;
        *dst64++ = *src64++;
        *dst64++ = *src64++;
        *dst64++ = *src64++;
        *dst64++ = *src64++;
    }
    while (offset--)
        *dst64++ = *src64++;
}
static void
copy_small(void *restrict dst, const void *restrict src, size_t size)
{
    const uint64_t  *restrict src64;
    uint64_t        *restrict dst64;

    src64 = (const uint64_t *restrict)src;
    dst64 = (uint64_t *restrict)dst;
    *dst64 = *src64;
}
void
*mem_cpy(void *restrict dst, const void *restrict src, const size_t size)
{
    const uint8_t   *restrict src8;
    uint8_t         *restrict dst8;
    size_t          offset;
    size_t          words;
    size_t          aligned_size;

    if (!src || !dst)
        return (NULL);
    if (size <= 8)
    {
        copy_small(dst, src, size);
        return (dst);
    }
    words = size / 8;
    aligned_size = words * 8;
    offset = size - aligned_size;
    copy_words(dst, src, words);
    if (offset)
    {
        src8 = (const uint8_t *restrict)src;
        src8 = &src8[aligned_size];
        dst8 = (uint8_t *restrict)dst;
        dst8 = &dst8[aligned_size];
        while (offset--)
            *dst8++ = *src8++;
    }
    return (dst);
}
```

---

As a practice in optimization I'm trying to get my memcpy re-creation as close in speed to the libc one as I can. I have used the following techniques to optimize my memcpy:

- Casting the data to as big a datatype as possible for copying.
- Unrolling the main loop 8 times.
- For data <= 8 bytes I bypass the main loop.

My results (I have added a naive 1 byte at a time memcpy for reference):

| Test case | `mem_cpy` | `mem_cpy_naive` | `memcpy` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| big string (1000 bytes) | 12.452919s | 212.728906s | **0.935605s** |
| small string (8 bytes) | 0.367271s | 1.413559s | **0.149886s** |

I feel I have exhausted the "low hanging fruit" in terms of optimization. I understand that the libc function could be optimized on a level not accessible to me writing only C, but I wonder if there's still something to be done here or is the next step to write it in assembly. To give a bit more clarification as to my motive for this. I study programming in a school that has performance constrains on our projects, but as of now we are only able to use standard C, so I can't go optimizing on assembly level yet. We are also not allowed to use libc and have to create our own versions of the standard functions we want to use so making my memcpy as fast as possible helps me hitting the performance goals in my projects. And it's great for learning obviously. I welcome any ideas!

Here is the code including the tests, can be compiled as is:

```c
#include <time.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

const size_t        iters = 100000000;

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Optimized memcpy
//
static void         copy_words(void *dst, const void *src, size_t words)
{
    const uint64_t  *src64;
    uint64_t        *dst64;
    uint64_t        pages;
    uint64_t        offset;

    pages = words / 8;
    offset = words - pages * 8;
    src64 = (const uint64_t *)src;
    dst64 = (uint64_t *)dst;
    while (pages--)
    {
        *dst64++ = *src64++;
        *dst64++ = *src64++;
        *dst64++ = *src64++;
        *dst64++ = *src64++;
        *dst64++ = *src64++;
        *dst64++ = *src64++;
        *dst64++ = *src64++;
        *dst64++ = *src64++;
    }
    while (offset--)
        *dst64++ = *src64++;
}

static void         copy_small(void *dst, const void *src, size_t size)
{
    const uint64_t  *src64;
    uint64_t        *dst64;

    src64 = (const uint64_t *)src;
    dst64 = (uint64_t *)dst;
    *dst64 = *src64;
}

void                *mem_cpy(void *dst, const void *src, const size_t size)
{
    const uint8_t   *src8;
    uint8_t         *dst8;
    size_t          offset;
    size_t          words;
    size_t          aligned_size;

    if (!src || !dst)
        return (NULL);
    if (size <= 8)
    {
        copy_small(dst, src, size);
        return (dst);
    }
    words = size / 8;
    aligned_size = words * 8;
    offset = size - aligned_size;
    copy_words(dst, src, words);
    if (offset)
    {
        src8 = (const uint8_t *)src;
        src8 = &src8[aligned_size];
        dst8 = (uint8_t *)dst;
        dst8 = &dst8[aligned_size];
        while (offset--)
            *dst8++ = *src8++;
    }
    return (dst);
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Naive memcpy
//
void                *mem_cpy_naive(void *dst, const void *src, size_t n)
{
    const uint8_t   *src8;
    uint8_t         *dst8;

    if (src == NULL)
        return (NULL);
    src8 = (const uint8_t *)src;
    dst8 = (uint8_t *)dst;
    while (n--)
        *dst8++ = *src8++;
    return (dst);
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Tests
//
int         test(int (*f)(), char *test_name)
{   
    clock_t begin = clock();
    f();
    clock_t end = clock();
    double time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("%s: %f\n", test_name, time_spent);
    return (1);
}

char        *big_data()
{
    char    *out;
    size_t  i;

    out = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 1000);
    i = 0;
    while (i < 1000)
    {
        out[i] = 'a';
        i++;
    }
    return (out);
}

int         test1()
{
    char    *src;
    char    *dst;
    size_t  i;

    src = big_data();
    dst = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 1000);
    i = 0;
    while (i < iters)
    {
        mem_cpy(dst, src, 1000);
        i++;
    }
    return (1);
}


int         test2()
{
    char    *src;
    char    *dst;
    size_t  i;

    src = big_data();
    dst = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 1000);
    i = 0;
    while (i < iters)
    {
        mem_cpy_naive(dst, src, 1000);
        i++;
    }
    return (1);
}

int         test3()
{
    char    *src;
    char    *dst;
    size_t  i;

    src = big_data();
    dst = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 1000);
    i = 0;
    while (i < iters)
    {
        memcpy(dst, src, 1000);
        i++;
    }
    return (1);
}

int         test4()
{
    char    *src;
    char    *dst;
    size_t  i;

    src = "12345678";
    dst = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 8);
    i = 0;
    while (i < iters)
    {
        mem_cpy(dst, src, 8);
        i++;
    }
    return (1);
}

int         test5()
{
    char    *src;
    char    *dst;
    size_t  i;

    src = "12345678";
    dst = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 8);
    i = 0;
    while (i < iters)
    {
        mem_cpy_naive(dst, src, 8);
        i++;
    }
    return (1);
}

int         test6()
{
    char    *src;
    char    *dst;
    size_t  i;

    src = "12345678";
    dst = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 8);
    i = 0;
    while (i < iters)
    {
        memcpy(dst, src, 8);
        i++;
    }
    return (1);
}

int         main(void)
{
    test(test1, "User memcpy (big string)");
    test(test2, "User memcpy naive (big string)");
    test(test3, "Libc memcpy (big string)");
    test(test4, "User memcpy");
    test(test5, "USer memcpy naive");
    test(test6, "Libc memcpy");
}
```

I won't paste the assembly, since I think it's more convenient to just put a link to compiler explorer:

https://godbolt.org/z/Yva9EaPrP

Comment: One obvious optimization is you didn't declare the parameters `dest` and `src` with the qualifier `restrict` ( https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/restrict ), as in libc. Like so: `void *memcpy(void *restrict dest, const void *restrict src, size_t size)`

Comment: Great catch! Now my tests output as follows (suscpicious, I did add a print in the end to make sure compiler doesn't skip the loop):

User memcpy (big string): 1.639461
Libc memcpy (big string): 2.749912

Comment: Could be yours is being inlined while libc's isn't. What about if you declare `mem_cpy` with `__attribute__((noinline))` (GCC/clang) / `__declspec(noinline)` (MSVC)?

Comment: I did as you suggested (first example, using gcc) and results were identical.

Comment: Then I would guess the reason yours is faster is because of cache effects and/or static (your code) vs. dynamic (libc) linkage.

Comment: I tested it on a more "real world" example with a dynamic array implementation I have been working on (std::vector in C) and now I'm getting identical performance on my array tests using libc memcpy compared to my own. There used to be about a 20% difference in this particular test. So I'm pretty happy about the results as is!

Comment: I hope the .h file declaration of `mem_cpy()` does **not** include `const` with `size_t size`.  It is noise in the _declaration_.

Comment: Tests do not cover that cases where the buffers are not meeting max alignment.  `malloc()` provides such, but `memcpy()` usage is not limited to that.

Comment: Adding the table was a good edit, but editing the code is not allowed after an answer has been posted because everyone should be able to see the code that was reviewed in the answer. Please read [What should I do when someone answers](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). You can ask a new question with a link to this question as a follow up question if you want a review of the new code.

Comment: I left the original code in the end though, is that not allowed?

Comment: Or should I make an answer to this thread to show updated results and code, since there's not really a question to go with that but I feel it's relevant information?

Comment: You could post your new code and the results as an answer, but only if the answer is a review of some sort. Tell us what you improved and why, why it's better than the original. That would work nicely.

Comment: I have added the new results, tests and code and an overview of changes as an answer.

Answer (score 7):

### Fix buffer overrun in `copy_small`

As you've currently written it, and as Toby previously pointed out, `copy_small` always writes 8 bytes to `dest`, even when `size < 8`. This is a major memory safety bug as it writes past the end of the `dest` buffer.

```c
void
copy_small(void *restrict dst, const void *restrict src, size_t size)
{
    const uint64_t  *restrict src64;
    uint64_t        *restrict dst64;

    src64 = (const uint64_t *restrict)src;
    dst64 = (uint64_t *restrict)dst;
    *dst64 = *src64; // !DANGER WILL ROBINSON!
}
```

Here is how I would write `copy_small`. This is safe and, I believe, optimal.

```c
void copy_small(uint8_t *restrict dst, const uint8_t *restrict src, size_t size)
{
    if (size & 8) {
        *(uint64_t *restrict)dst = *(const uint64_t *restrict)src;
        return;
    }
    if (size & 4) {
        *(uint32_t *restrict)dst = *(const uint32_t *restrict)src;
        dst += 4;
        src += 4;
    }
    if (size & 2) {
        *(uint16_t *restrict)dst = *(const uint16_t *restrict)src;
        dst += 2;
        src += 2;
    }
    if (size & 1)
        *dst = *src;
}
```

### Don't time `malloc` in your tests

As Toby pointed out, you need to rewrite your tests so that any memory allocations are completed before the timer starts, otherwise you're contaminating your data by measuring `malloc` in addition to the copy routines.

### Qualify pointer arguments with `restrict`

As I said in the comments, your original code was missing the `restrict` qualifier (as with libc `memcpy`) on pointer arguments to `mem_cpy` and friends. This was the most significant missed optimization opportunity in your code, and as you say this change led to a significant speedup.

For "fairness," if you haven't done so already, add `restrict` to the pointer arguments of `mem_cpy_naive`. Note that you will need to compile with the option `-fno-tree-loop-distribute-patterns` to prevent GCC from optimizing `mem_cpy_naive` to a call to libc `memcpy`.

### Micro-optimizations

- You declared `copy_words` and `copy_small` with `static` linkage, presumably because you want them to be inlined, but in that case you should also declare them `inline` (i.e. `static inline`). Contrary to popular myth, the `inline` specifier *does* make the compiler significantly more likely to inline the function.
- Passing a null pointer to `memcpy` is *undefined behavior,* meaning you don't have to handle it gracefully. So, this /`if (!src || !dst) return (NULL)`/ is unnecessary. I'd replace it with an assertion /`assert(src && dst)`/ and compile with `-DNDEBUG` for the benchmarks. You can also declare your functions with `__attribute__((nonnull))`, which tells GCC to 1) raise a warning if it detects a null pointer being passed to the function and 2) optimize under the assumption that the pointer arguments are never null.
- Divisions and multiplications by powers of 2 are equivalent to right or left bit shifts by that power (which are faster). So all the instances of `x / 8` in your code can be replaced with `x >> 3` and all the `x * 8` can be replaced by `x << 3`. The compiler is probably smart enough to do this itself, but you might as well make it explicit.
- The `if (offset)` branch is unnecessary, and the loop it contains can be replaced with a call to `copy_small`. And you can make this change while still only calling `copy_small` once in `mem_cpy`. Do you see how?

### Style suggestions

- `copy_words` and `copy_small` don't have to follow the `memcpy` API exactly. It's a lot less verbose if their `dest` and `src` arguments are respectively `uint64_t*` and `uint8_t*` instead of `void*`.
- Declaring a bunch of uninitialized variables at the top of the function was necessary in ANSI C, but in modern C it's bad style and potentially dangerous if you forget to initialize one of them. As much as possible, variables should both be declared (as `const` when they aren't modified) and initialized directly before they're used.
- As Toby said, the unnecessary parentheses around return values are confusing to the reader.
- As Toby also said, the use of the term `pages` for something other than a page is confusing. I would replace that with `chunks` or similar.

### Disagreements with Toby

- I wouldn't worry about exotic/nonexistent platforms where `CHAR_BIT != 8` or `uint64_t` isn't supported. If you were actually implementing `memcpy` for GCC, you might have to worry about this. But otherwise, no.
- When I write C code, I try to make it compatible with C++ if possible. So, since C++ requires it, I'm in favor of casting calls to `malloc` to the type of pointer they're being assigned to.

### Your code, as I would write it:

```cpp
#include <assert.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#if !defined(__GNUC__) && !defined(__attribute__) // no GCC attribute syntax
#define __attribute__(X)
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus // C++
extern "C" {

#if defined(__GNUC__) || defined(_MSC_VER) || defined(__restrict)
#define restrict __restrict
#elif !defined(restrict) // restrict or __restrict not supported in C++
#define restrict
#endif

#endif

static inline __attribute__((nonnull))
void copy_small(uint8_t *restrict dst, const uint8_t *restrict src, size_t size)
{
    if (size >= 8) {
        *(uint64_t *restrict)dst = *(const uint64_t *restrict)src;
        return;
    }
    if (size >= 4) {
        *(uint32_t *restrict)dst = *(const uint32_t *restrict)src;
        dst += 4;
        src += 4;
    }
    if (size & 2) {
        *(uint16_t *restrict)dst = *(const uint16_t *restrict)src;
        dst += 2;
        src += 2;
    }
    if (size & 1)
        *dst = *src;
}

static inline __attribute__((nonnull))
void copy64(uint64_t *restrict dst, const uint64_t *restrict src, size_t n) {
    size_t chunks = n >> 3;
    size_t offset = n - (chunks << 3);

    while (chunks--) {
        *dst++ = *src++;
        *dst++ = *src++;
        *dst++ = *src++;
        *dst++ = *src++;
        *dst++ = *src++;
        *dst++ = *src++;
        *dst++ = *src++;
        *dst++ = *src++;
    }
    while (offset--)
        *dst++ = *src++;
}

__attribute__((nonnull))
void *mem_cpy(void *restrict dst, const void *restrict src, size_t size) {
    assert(dst && src);

    uint8_t *dst8 = (uint8_t*)dst;
    const uint8_t *src8 = (const uint8_t*)src;

    if (size > 8) {
        const size_t qwords = size >> 3;

        copy64((uint64_t*)dst, (const uint64_t*)src, qwords);

        const size_t aligned_size = qwords << 3;

        size -= aligned_size;
        dst8 += aligned_size;
        src8 += aligned_size;
    }

    copy_small(dst8, src8, size);

    return dst;
}

/* GCC optimizes this to a call to libc memcpy unless compiled with
 * -fno-tree-loop-distribute-patterns
 */
__attribute__((nonnull))
void *mem_cpy_naive(void *restrict dst, const void *restrict src, size_t size) {
    assert(dst && src);

    uint8_t *restrict dst8 = (uint8_t*)dst;
    const uint8_t *restrict src8 = (const uint8_t*)src;

    while (size--)
        *dst8++ = *src8++;

    return dst;
}

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Comment: You shouldn't have to cast pointers in C++ either, since you should use `new` there, or perhaps a `std::vector`, instead of `malloc()`. If it's about compiling with a C++ compiler, then that shouldn't work here because `restrict` is not a valid C++ keyword.

Comment: Did you look at the code I wrote at the bottom? I addressed the `restrict` issue (not difficult).

Comment: The X32 ABI isn't really maintained, is likely to be deprecated in the near future and I don't think any distros support it. But, maybe it would be better to go with OP's idea and just use `uint64_t` to copy with, since it should still be close to optimal even on most platforms with a native word size less than 64 bits.

Comment: FWIW I dropped the `size_t` idea, if nothing else it makes my code easier to read.

Comment: Would this be a cheapo lazy solution or could it work if I just bitmasked the < 8 byte chunk. Something like `mask = (1 << bytes) - 1; *dst = *src & mask` ??

Comment: @jkoskela No because it will still write zero bytes out of bounds.

Comment: `(const uint64_t *restrict)src` risks UB as casting to a stricter alignment is not guaranteed.

Comment: I have updated test and results. Now the results seem more aligned with expectations.

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> const uint64_t  *restrict src64;
> ```

Portability problem - `uint64_t` is only defined if the platform has a type of exactly 64 bits.  Consider using `uint_fast64_t` (or perhaps `uintmax_t`) instead.

> ```
> pages = words / 8;
> offset = words - pages * 8;
> ```

Another portability problem - assumes `CHAR_BIT` is 64/8 = 8.  Use `sizeof *src64` instead.

The terminology is strange and confusing.  Why are we calling bytes "words" and words "pages"?

> ```
> src64 = (const uint64_t *restrict)src;
> dst64 = (uint64_t *restrict)dst;
> ```

I don't see where this code guarantees that `src64` and `dst64` are suitably aligned for read and write as 64-bit quantities.  This means that the code will work on some architectures (possibly with performance problems) and fail completely on others (perhaps raising `SIGBUS` if you're lucky).

The explicit casts are unnecessary given that `src` and `dst` are both `void*`, which converts implicitly to any object pointer.  And there's no need to declare separately from initialising.

I don't see how `copy_small` honours its `size` argument.  It always seems to copy a full `uint64_t`, potentially clobbering more than requested (and possibly writing outside its legitimate bounds).

---

The tests have problems, too.  Let's look at `test1()` as a representative example:

> ```
> int         test1()
> {
>     char    *src;
>     char    *dst;
>     size_t  i;
> ```

Again, declare where we initialise.

> ```
>     src = big_data();
>     dst = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 1000);
> ```

There's no need to write an explicit cast to convert from `void*`.  The multiplication by 1 has no effect.

Why do we continue if allocation gives us back a null pointer?  That's very slapdash.

More importantly, why are we including `malloc()` call in our timings?  That's going to dominate the result.

> ```
>     i = 0;
>     while (i < iters)
>     {
>         mem_cpy(dst, src, 1000);
>         i++;
>     }
> ```

That would be more readable as an ordinary `for` loop.

> ```
>     return (1);
> }
> ```

Why the pointless parens around the return value?  `return 1;` is more readable.

Comment: Can you elabroate on how `uint_fast64_t` would help? As for the compatibility, you are very correct. Just didn't get around to it yet.

Comment: `uint_fast64_t` is defined even if there's not a type of exactly 64 bits.  So it is more portable.  Perhaps `uintmax_t` would be an even better choice?

Comment: As for the copy small, I was thinking about that. Having all different types and checking it size is 6-8, 4-6 etc. seemed a bit overkill. As far as I understand malloc guarantees 64bit offset anyways. I played with the idea of still copying the data with a bit-mask though, to make extra sure only relevant data is copied, although I don't see a practical case in which that could become an issue.

Comment: What's wrong with a simple char-by-char approach for small copies?  That's what most `memcpy()` implementations do.  Yes, `malloc()` should return memory suitably aligned for any type, but that's no help when you need to copy (e.g.) a substring out of somewhere in the middle of a string, or from/to automatic ("stack") storage.

Comment: You are probably right that I should do a byte by byte. I was thinking I could squeeze a cycle or two there with using the wider type, but I guess compiler would optimize it away anyways. Need to do a couple of tests for that.

Comment: Oh and by the way I’m calling 64bit uints words and 8 * 64bits a page. As far as I understand that’s the naming of such things in the kernel, no?

Comment: On most platforms a page is 4KB, i.e. 512x64 bits.

Comment: 8 * 64 bits = 64 bytes is the typical size of a [cache line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3928995/how-do-cache-lines-work).

Comment: @jkoskela  "As far as I understand malloc guarantees 64bit offset anyways." --> No.

Comment: UV for stating a common hole: "I don't see where this code guarantees that src64 and dst64 are suitably aligned for read and write as 64-bit quantities.."

Answer (score 2):

## Updated results, tests and code

As per suggestions in this thread I have updated my code following several
suggestions from the answers. If I have incporporated your code in the result, I
want to note that I need to follow certain strict formatting rules so sorry if
I've changed the formatting in places.

### Test scenario

I have created the following test scenarion:

- Copy a constant amount of data, but changing the amount of bytes fed to memcpy
  each iteration and thus dividing the amount of iterations.
- Measure maximum throughput in MB/s to find a sweet spot. This could be
  considered the maximum theoretcial speed for the copy under optimal
  situations.

Test hardware:

```
AMD Ryzen 3 3100 4-Core Processor
cpu MHz     : 2199.410
cache size  : 512 KB
bogomips    : 7199.89
TLB size    : 3072 4K pages
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 43 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
```

Test (32 samples):

total bytes per iteration = 4294MB

| bytes / string | lib (s) | usr (s) | lib (MB/s) | usr (MB/s) | lib / usr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 19.419099 | 18.627787 | 221.17 | 230.57 | 1.042480 |
| 2 | 10.235309 | 9.164130 | 419.62 | 468.67 | **1.116888** |
| 4 | 5.488895 | 6.074278 | 782.48 | 707.07 | 0.903629 |
| 8 | 2.734126 | 2.450595 | 1570.87 | 1752.62 | 1.115699 |
| 16 | 1.358260 | 2.307924 | 3162.11 | 1860.97 | 0.588520 |
| 32 | 0.533698 | 1.219608 | 8047.56 | 3521.60 | 0.437598 |
| 64 | 0.269884 | 0.629097 | 15914.12 | 6827.19 | **0.429002** |
| 128 | 0.231149 | 0.376591 | 18580.95 | 11404.86 | 0.613793 |
| 256 | 0.101361 | 0.209152 | 42372.98 | 20535.15 | 0.484628 |
| 512 | 0.098064 | 0.146679 | 43797.59 | 29281.41 | 0.668562 |
| 1024 | 0.091359 | 0.122013 | 47011.98 | 35200.90 | 0.748764 |
| 2048 | 0.088001 | 0.124751 | 48805.89 | 34428.32 | 0.705413 |
| 4096 | 0.092047 | **0.117869** | 46660.59 | **36438.48** | 0.780926 |
| 8192 | **0.083935** | 0.121658 | **51170.16** | 35303.62 | 0.689926 |
| 16384 | 0.089955 | 0.132727 | 47745.73 | 32359.41 | 0.677745 |
| 32768 | 0.122094 | 0.177560 | 35177.55 | 24188.82 | 0.687621 |
| 65536 | 0.132070 | 0.175046 | 32520.39 | 24536.22 | 0.754487 |
| 131072 | 0.132693 | 0.155997 | 32367.70 | 27532.37 | 0.850613 |
| 262144 | 0.158665 | 0.172354 | 27069.41 | 24919.45 | 0.920576 |
| 524288 | 0.192556 | 0.197228 | 22305.03 | 21776.66 | 0.976312 |
| 1048576 | 0.195232 | 0.200701 | 21999.30 | 21399.83 | 0.972751 |
| 2097152 | 0.199710 | 0.206325 | 21506.02 | 20816.51 | 0.967939 |
| 4194304 | 0.916251 | 1.116313 | 4687.54 | 3847.46 | 0.820783 |
| 8388608 | 1.867847 | 1.933270 | 2299.42 | 2221.61 | 0.966159 |
| 16777216 | 1.920515 | 2.298106 | 2236.36 | 1868.92 | 0.835695 |
| 33554432 | 1.905867 | 2.115908 | 2253.55 | 2029.85 | 0.900732 |
| 67108864 | 1.533392 | 1.837277 | 2800.96 | 2337.68 | 0.834600 |
| 134217728 | 1.530375 | 1.882125 | 2806.48 | 2281.98 | 0.813110 |
| 268435456 | 1.405044 | 1.805629 | 3056.82 | 2378.65 | 0.778147 |
| 536870912 | 1.485964 | 1.877592 | 2890.36 | 2287.49 | 0.791420 |
| 1073741824 | 1.434760 | 1.869482 | 2993.51 | 2297.41 | 0.767464 |
| 2147483648 | 1.442237 | 1.838574 | 2977.99 | 2336.03 | 0.784432 |

### Updated code with tests

Improvements on the code since original:

- Usage of restrict keyword as suggested by @Ray Hamel
- Correction of the buffer overrun when copying a small string suggested by @Ray Hamel
- Corrections to tests such as not allocating memory inside the timed portion of
  the tests as suggested by @Toby Spleight and several others.
- For my use case I can expwect that the results ar not NULL so I have
  incorporated `__attribute__((nonull))` as suggested by @Ray Hamel.

```c
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

size_t      iters = 0; // 2^36

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Optimized memcpy
//

static inline void __attribute__((nonnull))
copy_small(uint8_t *restrict dst, const uint8_t *restrict src, size_t n)
{
    if (n >= 8)
    {
        *(uint64_t *restrict)dst = *(const uint64_t *restrict)src;
        return;
    }
    if (n >= 4)
    {
        *(uint32_t *restrict)dst = *(const uint32_t *restrict)src;
        dst += 4;
        src += 4;
    }
    if (n & 2)
    {
        *(uint16_t *restrict)dst = *(const uint16_t *restrict)src;
        dst += 2;
        src += 2;
    }
    if (n & 1)
        *dst = *src;
}

static inline void __attribute__((nonnull))
copy512(uint64_t *restrict dst, const uint64_t *restrict src, size_t n)
{
    size_t chunks;
    size_t offset;

    chunks = n >> 3;
    offset = n - (chunks << 3);
    while (chunks--)
    {
        *dst++ = *src++;
        *dst++ = *src++;
        *dst++ = *src++;
        *dst++ = *src++;
        *dst++ = *src++;
        *dst++ = *src++;
        *dst++ = *src++;
        *dst++ = *src++;
    }
    while (offset--)
        *dst++ = *src++;
}

void __attribute__((nonnull))
*mem_cpy(void *restrict dst, const void *restrict src, size_t n)
{
    uint8_t         *dst8;
    const uint8_t   *src8;
    size_t          qwords;
    size_t          aligned_size;

    dst8 = (uint8_t*)dst;
    src8 = (const uint8_t*)src;
    qwords = n >> 3;
    if (n > 8)
    {
        copy512((uint64_t*)dst, (const uint64_t*)src, qwords);
        return (dst);
    }
    aligned_size = qwords << 3;
    n -= aligned_size;
    dst8 += aligned_size;
    src8 += aligned_size;
    copy_small(dst8, src8, n);
    return (dst);
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Tests
//
double      test(int (*f)(char *, char *, size_t),
            char *test_data,
            char *test_dst,
            char *test_name,
            size_t i)
{   
    clock_t begin = clock();
    f(test_dst, test_data, i);
    clock_t end = clock();
    double time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    return (time_spent);
}

char        *make_string(size_t size)
{
    char    *out;
    size_t  i;

    out = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * size);
    i = 0;
    while (i < size)
    {
        out[i] = i % 128;
        i++;
    }
    return (out);
}

int         test_usr(char *dst, char *src, size_t bytes)
{
    size_t  i;

    i = 0;
    while (i < iters)
    {
        mem_cpy(dst, src, bytes);
        assert(memcmp(dst, src, bytes) == 0);
        i++;
    }
    return (1);
}

int         test_lib(char *dst, char *src, size_t bytes)
{
    size_t  i;

    i = 0;
    while (i < iters)
    {
        memcpy(dst, src, bytes);
        assert(memcmp(dst, src, bytes) == 0);
        i++;
    }
    return (1);
}

int         test_different_sizes()
{
    size_t  power;
    size_t  i;
    size_t  size;
    double  lib;
    double  usr;
    double  lmbs;
    double  umbs;
    char    *src;
    char    *dst;

    i = 0;
    power = 32;
    iters = pow(2, power);
    printf("total bytes per iteration = %zuMB\n", iters / (size_t)pow(10, 6));
    printf("| bytes / string | lib (s) | usr (s) | lib (MB/s) | usr (MB/s) | lib / usr |\n");
    printf("|---|---|---|---|---|\n");
    while (i < power)
    {
        size = pow(2, i);
        src = make_string(size);
        dst = make_string(size);
        lib = test(test_lib, src, dst, "LIB", size);
        usr = test(test_usr, src, dst, "USR", size);
        lmbs = ((size * iters) / pow(10, 6)) / lib;
        umbs = ((size * iters) / pow(10, 6)) / usr;
        printf("|%-10zu|%-10lf|%-10lf|%-10.2lf|%-10.2lf|%-10lf|\n",
                size, lib, usr, lmbs, umbs, lib / usr);
        iters /= 2;
        free(src);
        free(dst);
        i++;
    }
    return (1);
}

int         main(void)
{
    test_different_sizes();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you try this in MacOS, you’ll have an extreme fight on your hands. MacOS will at boot time install code optimised for your particular processor in a fixed place, this is done for memcpy, memmove , memset plus memset for two, four or eight byte values, and for some atomic operations.

The memcpy on my current computer uses vector instructions, uses caching instructions not available in C, and all the tricks in the book. You basically have no chance beating it. And if you beat it on one computer, it won’t work on another.

As far as your code is concerned: You should try to align the pointers first.

```
If count >= 1 and dst is not two-byte aligned -> copy 1 byte. 
If count >= 2 and dst is not four-byte aligned -> copy 2 byte.
If count >= 4 and dst is not eight-byte aligned -> copy 4 byte.
```

Then you copy eight bytes at a time, then another 4 if needed, another 2, and another byte.

Comment: I tried it on a MacBook Pro i9 2019. My code was still faster although not by as big of a margin as in the OP. Mac OS uses clang though even if you type GCC so I had to compile on clang. Surely my compiler can vectorize and use all tricks in the book as well since I'm using -O3, restrict etc.